# How to inject Renderer2 into custom service in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to inject Renderer2 into my custom service and it's failing with the error as below:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[Renderer2]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Renderer2]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Renderer2!
```

It's a brand new angular app created using cli and my custom service I created is:

```
import { Injectable, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FontsService {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { 
    console.log(this.renderer);
  }

  getFonts() {
    return 'Ubuntu';
  }

}
```

And app.module is very simply just providing the newly created service:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FontsService } from './fonts.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [FontsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any help please?

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17824 look at the last comment "As I can see Renderer2 don't work in services and work in components (in Angular 4.4.5)." Maybe just use it directly in component?

Comment: well, I'm using this service to create a link tag and insert that link tag into head after user selecting a particular font. I need this functionality in multiple places, so service seems a good option to handle that. But unfortunately Renderer2 which has methods to access dom isn't working in custom service.

Comment: would it be possible to use this as a directive instead?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Because it's not possible to inject renderer into service, I injected renderer into component and passed that renderer to service when calling the method of service from component. It works great, but the only downside is that you will have to pass that renderer reference always from wherever you are calling.

Answer (score 19):

There is the way which Angular using internally in webworkers, for example.

I've solved the problem with the code below:

```js
import { Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
class Service {
    private renderer: Renderer2;

    constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
        this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    }
}
```

Parameters of `RendererFactory2.createRenderer` method are:

- `hostElement` with type `any`
- `type` with type `RendererType2|null`

You can see that `(null, null)` parameters are here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e3140ae888ac4037a5f119efaec7b1eaf8726286/packages/core/src/render/api.ts#L129

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.